# Does using socket io mean giving up PHP and apache?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, socket.io

So I've started working a little with Node JS and socket io for building fast and stable real time web applications (I'm pretty newbie to those).
The thing is that up until now I've been using LAMP and I don't think I am ready to abandon apache and php for developing a website completely with node js.

Can anyone please tell me what is the standard structure of integrating socket io with apache?

Comment: Node.js server is separate from apache. You can use php for normal web requests and node.js for websockets.

Comment: Here is a search query using both the apache and socket.io tags.  Might be some helpful information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io+apache

Comment: close votes and downvotes are harsh IMHO - it's quite hard to get entry level information on what Socket.IO actually is, and where it fits in the stack.

Comment: @Esailija and don't forget Socket.IO is _not_ WebSockets!

Comment: @Alnitak oh right, well too late for edit :D

Answer (score 1):

For any Socket.IO web app you still need:

1. an HTTP server
2. a Socket.IO server

Node.js can do both those, but *can't* serve PHP content.

Apache can *only* do the HTTP / PHP parts.

It's perfectly possible to mix and match, but it's down to you do decide whether it's appropriate.

Comment: If you do a socket.io server, it also creates a http server necessary for the handshakes.

Comment: Sure, but that server is only for the handshakes, it won't serve his PHP content.

Comment: Yeah but if doesn't give up PHP and apache, he has PHP and apache for the normal web content :P ? Anyways maybe I misunderstood, have some upvotes.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point - if he _needs_ PHP, he has to keep Apache.  Otherwise he could do the whole thing in Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple technologies on the same Server using different ports,
with no further configuration needed.

If you however want to have PHP **and** node.js apps on the same port, maybe 80,
you need a proxy.

Using node.s on port 80 with the node-http-proxy module also works like a charm with websockets.

I was searching for a solutions for such a setup recently an ended up with what i wrote down here: http://nerdpress.org/2012/04/20/hosting-multiple-express-node-js-apps-on-port-80/